# How to PUT xml content using method ::http::geturl -method PUT

Tags: http, tcl, alm

When i tried with Fire Fox Open HttpRequest Addon, i was able to put sucessfully.

```
PUT http://12.222.20.17:8080/qcbin/rest/domains/test/projects/runtest/runs/385762
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
<Entity Type="run"> 
    <Fields> 
         <Field Name="status"> 
               <Value>Passed</Value> 
         </Field> 
     </Fields> 
</Entity>

 -- response --
200 OK
Server:  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

But i am trying to simulate same operation with TCL PUT method http package, i am getting Bad Request response

```
set xml {<Entity Type="run"><Fields><Field Name="status"><Value>Passed</Value></Field></Fields></Entity>}
set Headers(Cookie) $cookie
set Headers(Accept) "application/xml"
set Headers(Content-Type) "application/xml"
set Headers(Content) $xml
set token [::http::geturl "http://12.222.20.17:8080/qcbin/rest/domains/test/projects/runtest/runs/385762" -method PUT -headers [array get Headers]]
```

Response

```
% ::http::data $token
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><QCRestException><Id>qcco
re.general-error</Id><Title>Bad Request</Title><StackTrace>javax.ws.rs.WebApplic
ationException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog&#xD;

 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]&#xD;
        at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.entity.xml.JAXBXmlProvider.
readFrom(JAXBXmlProvider.java:113)&#xD;
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ServerInjectableFactory$Enti
tyParam.getValue(ServerInjectableFactory.java:190)&#xD;
```

I am not sure where i am missing, could some one please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an XML document in your request via PUT, assuming you've got the document serialized into a string obtainable with `$theXML`, you just do this:

```
# Type *might* need to be text/xml
http::geturl $theServiceURL -method PUT -type application/xml -query $theXML
```

Of course, you've got to make sure that you handle the token that it returns right, and so on. The `http` package is still pretty low-level. (For example, you'll probably have to use `http::config` to set what MIME types you get in the response, and you'll need to handle redirects and cookies for sessions yourself.)

---

Sending JSON instead? The type then becomes `application/json`. Easy!